# Reading char like "ę" using java iText

Tags: java

I have problem with reading char like "ę". There are two option to add text to new document

1.

```
document.add(new Paragraph("ę", f1)
```

where f1 is a Font

2.

```
Paragraph p=new Paragraph ("ę");
p.setFont(f1);
p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
document.add(p);
```

In first situation the character "ę" is written correctly but I can't set the alignment. In second situation I can set alignment but the character "ę" is written incorrectly. I want to connect these two examples: the character "ę" is written correctly and I can set the alignment.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does using `"\u0119"` instead of `"ę"` help?

Comment: I tried Paragraph p=new Paragraph ("\u0119") but it doesn't work.